# Error 1721: AsusInstallVerifier.exe (A program required for this install to complete could not be run)

Tags: updates, asus-laptop, windows-installer, software-update

Ever since installing `Asus FrameworkService version 1.0.4.1`, every single update has failed with message:

```
Error 1721.
  There is a problem with this Windows Installer package.
  A program required for this install to complete could not be run.
  Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Action: verifyInstall
```

Log:

```
Action 7:17:30: INSTALL. 
Action start 7:17:30: INSTALL.
Action 7:17:30: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 7:17:30: FindRelatedProducts.
FindRelatedProducts: Found application: {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Action ended 7:17:30: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:30: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
Action start 7:17:30: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 7:17:30: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:30: ValidateProductID. 
Action start 7:17:30: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 7:17:30: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:30: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
Action start 7:17:30: CostInitialize.
Action ended 7:17:31: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:31: FileCost. Computing space requirements
Action start 7:17:31: FileCost.
Action ended 7:17:31: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:31: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
Action start 7:17:31: CostFinalize.
Action ended 7:17:31: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:31: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
Action start 7:17:31: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 7:17:31: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 1.
Action 7:17:31: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 7:17:31: ExecuteAction.
Action start 7:17:33: INSTALL.
Action start 7:17:33: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 7:17:33: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:33: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 7:17:33: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 7:17:33: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: CostInitialize.
Action ended 7:17:33: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: FileCost.
Action ended 7:17:33: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: CostFinalize.
Action ended 7:17:33: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 7:17:33: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:33: InstallValidate.
Action ended 7:17:33: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action start 7:17:33: INSTALL.
Action start 7:17:33: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 7:17:33: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:33: LaunchConditions.
Action ended 7:17:33: LaunchConditions. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 7:17:33: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: CostInitialize.
Action ended 7:17:33: CostInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: FileCost.
Action ended 7:17:33: FileCost. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: CostFinalize.
Action ended 7:17:33: CostFinalize. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:33: MigrateFeatureStates.
Action ended 7:17:33: MigrateFeatureStates. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:33: InstallValidate.
Action ended 7:17:36: InstallValidate. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: RemoveExistingProducts.
Action ended 7:17:36: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:36: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 7:17:36: InstallInitialize. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: CloseFrameworkEXE.
Action ended 7:17:36: CloseFrameworkEXE. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: ProcessComponents.
Action ended 7:17:36: ProcessComponents. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: UnRegisterSchedule.
Action ended 7:17:36: UnRegisterSchedule. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: UnpublishFeatures.
Action ended 7:17:36: UnpublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: RemoveRegistryValues.
Action ended 7:17:36: RemoveRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: RemoveFiles.
Action ended 7:17:36: RemoveFiles. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:36: RemoveFolders.
Action ended 7:17:36: RemoveFolders. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: CreateFolders.
Action ended 7:17:36: CreateFolders. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: InstallFiles.
Action ended 7:17:36: InstallFiles. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: WriteRegistryValues.
Action ended 7:17:36: WriteRegistryValues. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: RegisterUser.
Action ended 7:17:36: RegisterUser. Return value 0.
Action start 7:17:36: verifyInstall.
Action ended 7:17:36: verifyInstall. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: RegisterProduct.
Action ended 7:17:36: RegisterProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: PublishFeatures.
Action ended 7:17:36: PublishFeatures. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: PublishProduct.
Action ended 7:17:36: PublishProduct. Return value 1.
Action start 7:17:36: InstallFinalize.
Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: verifyInstall, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\, command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\AsusInstallVerifier.exe" -mv -d "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\hashes.hash" -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\asus_framework.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\asus_framework.exe.manifest" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\WindowID\WindowID.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\AsTaskSched.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\RegSchdTask.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\killproc.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\AsTaskSchedArg.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi\build\Release\ffi_bindings.node" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\libeay32.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\openssl.cnf" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\openssl.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\ssleay32.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\certificate.pem" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\certrequest.csr" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\privatekey.pem" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\ssl.bat" 
MSI (s) (24:F4) [07:17:38:018]: 
Action ended 7:17:38: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
Action ended 7:17:38: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(N): UpgradeCode = {CD8D2BAE-0675-458D-B38E-814A81FD0FB0}
Property(N): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\
Property(N): WINDOWID = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\WindowID\
Property(N): SCHEDULE = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\
Property(N): ffi = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi\
Property(N): ffiRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi\build\Release\
Property(N): ref = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref\
Property(N): refRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref\build\Release\
Property(N): SSL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\
Property(N): openssl = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\
Property(N): View = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\view\
Property(N): WINDOWIDDLL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\
Property(N): ffibuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi\build\
Property(N): NodeModel = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\
Property(N): refbuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref\build\
Property(N): COMPANYFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\
Property(N): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(N): TARGETDIR = E:\
Property(N): Installed = 00:00:00
Property(N): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(N): Manufacturer = ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
Property(N): ProductCode = {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Property(N): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(N): ProductName = ASUS Framework Service
Property(N): ProductVersion = 1.0.4.1
Property(N): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(N): PackageCode = {4417F738-8D57-4782-AAB7-994D1E5FAF97}
Property(N): ProductState = 5
Property(N): UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE = {EA6A87BE-8AD3-40D2-944C-9DF5FBFF4332}
Property(N): CLIENTPROCESSID = 25848
Property(N): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(N): REMOVE = ALL
Property(N): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(N): PRODUCTLANGUAGE = 1033
Property(N): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(N): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(N): VersionNT = 603
Property(N): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(N): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(N): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(N): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(N): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(N): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(N): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(N): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(N): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(N): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(N): TempFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(N): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(N): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(N): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(N): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\
Property(N): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Favorites\
Property(N): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(N): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Documents\
Property(N): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(N): RecentFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(N): SendToFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(N): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(N): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(N): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\
Property(N): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Pictures\
Property(N): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(N): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(N): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(N): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(N): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(N): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(N): GPTSupport = 1
Property(N): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(N): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(N): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(N): Msix64 = 6
Property(N): Intel = 6
Property(N): PhysicalMemory = 16234
Property(N): VirtualMemory = 10088
Property(N): LogonUser = <User>
Property(N): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3257890487-2031205339-215001084-1001
Property(N): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(N): ComputerName = LAPTOP
Property(N): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(N): ScreenX = 1024
Property(N): ScreenY = 768
Property(N): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(N): BorderTop = 1
Property(N): BorderSide = 1
Property(N): TextHeight = 16
Property(N): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(N): ColorBits = 32
Property(N): TTCSupport = 1
Property(N): Time = 7:17:38
Property(N): Date = 1/21/2021
Property(N): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.4084.0
Property(N): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.19041.546
Property(N): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(N): AdminUser = 1
Property(N): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(N): Privileged = 1
Property(N): USERNAME = <User>
Property(N): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\4186b.msi
Property(N): OriginalDatabase = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\4186b.msi
Property(N): UILevel = 5
Property(N): Preselected = 1
Property(N): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(N): ROOTDRIVE = E:\
Property(N): CostingComplete = 1
Property(N): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(N): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(N): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(N): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
CustomAction  returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 7:17:38: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 3.
Action ended 7:17:38: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(S): UpgradeCode = {CD8D2BAE-0675-458D-B38E-814A81FD0FB0}
Property(S): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\
Property(S): WINDOWID = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\WindowID\
Property(S): SCHEDULE = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\
Property(S): ffi = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\
Property(S): ffiRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(S): ref = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\
Property(S): refRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(S): regedit = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\
Property(S): regwin32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(S): SSL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\
Property(S): openssl = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\
Property(S): View = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\view\
Property(S): WINDOWIDDLL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\
Property(S): ffibuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\prebuilds\
Property(S): NodeModel = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\
Property(S): refbuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\prebuilds\
Property(S): vbs = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\prebuilds\
Property(S): COMPANYFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\
Property(S): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = E:\
Property(S): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(S): Manufacturer = ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
Property(S): ProductCode = {EA6A87BE-8AD3-40D2-944C-9DF5FBFF4332}
Property(S): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(S): ProductName = ASUS Framework Service
Property(S): ProductVersion = 2.0.2.2
Property(S): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(S): WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED = {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Property(S): PackageCode = {E911A42D-5BF2-493B-9F9E-66C3B8B0D4D0}
Property(S): ProductState = -1
Property(S): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(S): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(S): CLIENTPROCESSID = 25848
Property(S): USERNAME = <User>
Property(S): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(S): ROOTDRIVE = E:\
Property(S): MIGRATE = {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Property(S): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(S): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
Property(S): SECONDSEQUENCE = 1
Property(S): ADDLOCAL = ProductFeature
Property(S): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(S): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(S): VersionNT = 603
Property(S): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(S): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(S): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(S): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(S): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(S): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(S): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(S): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(S): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(S): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(S): TempFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(S): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(S): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(S): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(S): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\
Property(S): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Favorites\
Property(S): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(S): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Documents\
Property(S): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(S): RecentFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(S): SendToFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(S): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(S): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(S): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\
Property(S): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Pictures\
Property(S): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(S): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(S): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(S): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(S): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(S): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(S): GPTSupport = 1
Property(S): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(S): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(S): Msix64 = 6
Property(S): Intel = 6
Property(S): PhysicalMemory = 16234
Property(S): VirtualMemory = 10087
Property(S): LogonUser = <User>
Property(S): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3257890487-2031205339-215001084-1001
Property(S): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ComputerName = LAPTOP
Property(S): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(S): ScreenX = 1024
Property(S): ScreenY = 768
Property(S): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(S): BorderTop = 1
Property(S): BorderSide = 1
Property(S): TextHeight = 16
Property(S): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(S): ColorBits = 32
Property(S): TTCSupport = 1
Property(S): Time = 7:17:38
Property(S): Date = 1/21/2021
Property(S): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.4084.0
Property(S): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.19041.546
Property(S): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(S): AdminUser = 1
Property(S): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(S): Privileged = 1
Property(S): DATABASE = C:\WINDOWS\Installer\8d86a6.msi
Property(S): OriginalDatabase = FrameworkService.msi
Property(S): UILevel = 5
Property(S): Preselected = 1
Property(S): CostingComplete = 1
Property(S): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(S): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Action ended 7:17:38: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action ended 7:17:38: INSTALL. Return value 3.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {CD8D2BAE-0675-458D-B38E-814A81FD0FB0}
Property(C): INSTALLFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\
Property(C): WINDOWID = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\WindowID\
Property(C): SCHEDULE = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\Schedule\
Property(C): ffi = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\
Property(C): ffiRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(C): ref = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\
Property(C): refRelease = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(C): regedit = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\
Property(C): regwin32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\prebuilds\win32-ia32\
Property(C): SSL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\
Property(C): openssl = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\ssl\openssl\
Property(C): View = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\view\
Property(C): WINDOWIDDLL = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\dll\
Property(C): ffibuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ffi-napi\prebuilds\
Property(C): NodeModel = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\
Property(C): refbuild = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\ref-napi\prebuilds\
Property(C): vbs = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ArmouryDevice\node_modules\registry-js\prebuilds\
Property(C): COMPANYFOLDER = C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): TARGETDIR = E:\
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 1
Property(C): Manufacturer = ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.
Property(C): ProductCode = {EA6A87BE-8AD3-40D2-944C-9DF5FBFF4332}
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): ProductName = ASUS Framework Service
Property(C): ProductVersion = 2.0.2.2
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = WIX_DOWNGRADE_DETECTED;WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED
Property(C): WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED = {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Property(C): PackageCode = {E911A42D-5BF2-493B-9F9E-66C3B8B0D4D0}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 25848
Property(C): MsiSystemRebootPending = 1
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT = 603
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 603
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 9600
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 0
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\WINDOWS\system32\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Documents\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<User>\Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 16234
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 10121
Property(C): LogonUser = <User>
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-3257890487-2031205339-215001084-1001
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ComputerName = LAPTOP
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 1033
Property(C): ScreenX = 1920
Property(C): ScreenY = 1080
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 23
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 7:17:38
Property(C): Date = 1/21/2021
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.8.4084.0
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.3.19041.546
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = <User>
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = E:\
Property(C): MIGRATE = {CB0E3BB6-3F2F-401E-B1D4-E23C582ACB11}
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): CostingComplete = 0
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 1/21/2021  7:17:38 ===
MSI (c) (F8:B4) [07:17:38:351]: Product: ASUS Framework Service -- Installation failed.

MSI (c) (F8:B4) [07:17:38:351]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: ASUS Framework Service. Product Version: 2.0.2.2. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused when the installer copies the new `AsusInstallVerifier.exe` then it attempts to remove the older version installed, resulting in the old `.msi` attempting to run the new `AsusInstallVerifier.exe`, which crashes and the installer rolls back the changes.

To fix this, find the `.msi` cached by `msiserver` service: 
 <sup>*(This fix can be applied to other Asus packages that have similar error)*</sup>

1. Open `regedit` via <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Search for the package [`FrameworkService`] in:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData
   ```
3. Once found, look for the `InstallSource` key within `InstallProperties`
4. Open the folder from the `InstallSource` key → Right-click on the `.msi` → Uninstall